# Unsupported operand types on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.4, dropdownlistfor

How can I solve this on *Laravel 5.4*?

```
{!! Form::select('kecama',
      [''=>'--- Pilih Kecamatan ---'] + $kecamamatans,
      '',
      array(
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'id'=>'kecama'
      )
    );
!!}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you only pluck `$kecamamatans` in your controller before passing to view. In that case you need to use `toArray()`

Try this:

```
{!! Form::select(
      'kecama', 
      [''=>'--- Pilih Kecamatan ---'] + $kecamamatans->toArray(),
      '',
      array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'kecama')
    );
!!}
```

And change your controller code like below:

```
public function myform() 
{ 
    $kecamatans = DB::table('kecamatans')->pluck("nama_kecamatan", "id_kecamata‌​n"); 
    return view('register', compact('kecamatans')); 
}
```

Comment: when i run that code, the error message show: "Undefined variable: kecamatans"

Comment: public function myform()
    {
        $kecamatans = DB::table('kecamatans')->pluck("nama_kecamatan","id_kecamatan")->all();
        return view('register',compact('kecamatans'));
    }

Comment: public function selectAjax(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $desas = DB::table('desas')->where('id_kecamatan',$request->id_kecamatan)->pluck("nama_desa","id_desa")->all();
            $data = view('ajax-select',compact('desas'))->render();
            return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
        }
    }

Comment: still same, 
Undefined variable: kecamatans on register.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

in your Controller inside the create and edit make sure to have the following:

```
$person= Kecamatans::pluck("nama_kecamatan","id_kecamata‌​n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had face the same issue but the answer save my life is 
[Unsupported operand types in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123831/unsupported-operand-types-in-laravel-5-4)
Your question is similar with the above link.

My problem was that i was trying to merge the array value with undefined variable.

Please check & confirm you your are trying to merge the array variables or these are having different.

I had seen in your comment that you had passed the variable **kecamatans** and tring to merge with variable **$kecamamatans** both are looks different variable that's why it causing the issue.