# Unsupported operand types in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[Error page recieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twJcD.png)
This is the code block where the error originates. How do I handle this code snippet, I need it to work on laravel 5.4 the $extras variable is an array.

```
/**
 * Map to configuration
 *
 * @param $keys
 * @param $config_var
 * @param $extras
 * @return array
 */
private function map_to_config($keys, $config_var, $extras = [])
{
    try {
        $configArray =
            array_map(function ($string) use ($keys, $extras) {
              line 132 where the error is-->  return array_combine($keys, explode(":", $string)) + $extras;
            }, explode(",", $config_var));
        return array_filter($configArray);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What variables are you using? You should add more info if you want people to help you. It looks like the `+` is trying to add up 2 types, but without more info, no one knows :)

Comment: @Robert I've added more details

Comment: There's still no input there..

Comment: What error are you getting? And what does this code have to do with laravel?

Comment: I've added an image @jedrzej.kurylo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**array_combine** returns **FALSE** if number of values in arrays given as arguments is different. That's probably a reason why you're getting an error about **unsupported operand types** - you're trying to combine a boolean with an array.

Comment: Let me look into what you just said

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add the support file for the database which made the array empty so it couldn't combine the two arrays. Thanks for the insight.